# how do i iterate through one dictionaries and return values from another dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

So, I am looking for a solution to this problem - I have two dictionaries that I am working on, I want to be able to pass the key of the one dictionary and iterate through the values of the second dictionary that corresponds to the value of the first dictionary. 
Here is am example -

```
products = {"V14LC": "A", "V15LC": "A", "V20LC": "B", "V20LCACSPV": "B", "VPRC": "A", "V25LC": "B,I", "V28LC": "B,28,I"}

cases = {"case1": "BDH", "case5": "BCD", "case5c": "BCC", "case8D": "DD", "case8DC": "CDD", "case12": "CDH", "case14": "DEH", "case15": "CCDD"}
```

**input - V20LC (this has the value of "B")** so i should look for that value in the second dictionary (cases) and return all the keys that have that value.

**output needed - case1, case5, case5c** (because it has a "b" as a substring of its values).

Comment: What have  you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? The "smart" way to do this might be beyond you, but there's a very simple brute force solution if you just know how to look up values by key in dictionaries, write `for` loops over dictionary values, and check strings for substrings.

Comment: i am new to python, but here's what i tried -

def find_key(dic, val):
    return [k for k, v in dic.iteritems() if v == val][0]
print(find_key(products, "A"))
I am only able to get the one key though..

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? You know how to look up the value of `'V20LC'` in `products`, no? `val = products['V20LC']`. Then you simply iterate over your dictionary checking for keys with that value...

Comment: Don't try to paste what you tried into a comment; edit the question. Comments are tiny, don't allow formatting, etc.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is almost the simple brute solution in pseudocode. So if you really can't write this, write the parts you can write in Python, and fill in the gaps with pseudocode. Like `for each value in cases (I don't know how to write this): if letter in value: print(key that goes with this value)`. Someone can then show you how to do exactly the parts you couldn't figure out.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - that was just an example, I want the user to enter whatever value like 'V20LC' and then prints the corresponding values from cases dictionary.

Comment: OK, so **again** what is the problem *exactly*? Because now it sounds like the issue is getting user input...

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a nice function to do that:

```
def search_dict (x): return [key for key, value in cases.items() if products [x] in value]
```

This will return a list of keys in cases if they have the value of products [x] in them